# Docker service wait for mongorestore finish

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to create a docker-compose file and let every other service wait for mongo to finish the `mongorestore` command.
Is there any approach to do this?

I have to try `wait-for` and `depones_on`, but none of them are working as expected.

There will be a period mongo is doing restore and indexing. The port is listening but from node, it just show connection failed

The command as below:

```
command:
      ./wait-for-it.sh mongo:27017 -t 1200 -s -- yarn start-dev
```

And the error shows

```
[2021-04-24 06:04:54.520] [ERROR] -  - process -  - uncaughtException Error: Cannot connect to mongodb://mongo:27017/dev, exiting.
[2021-04-24 06:04:54.520] [ERROR] -  - process -  -     at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/oo/dev/node_modules/dev/index.coffee:13:11)
[2021-04-24 06:04:54.520] [ERROR] -  - process -  -     at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
[2021-04-24 06:04:54.520] [ERROR] -  - process -  -     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
[2021-04-24 06:04:54.520] [ERROR] -  - process -  -     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
```

Comment: Nope, this is not possible with docker resources. Docker has no concept of, e.g., a readiness probe. There are [workarounds](https://8thlight.com/blog/dariusz-pasciak/2016/10/17/docker-compose-wait-for-dependencies.html) when the service itself takes a while to start up. For your specific case, however, there is no way to determine when mongo is done restoring, thus we cannot inspect an external port to determin whether the restore has been completed.

Comment: @Turing85 thank you for the quick response. Do you know if there any mechanism on the mongo side that will block connection when restoring?

Comment: Sorry, have to pass on this one. I am not an expert on mongo administration.